# Can I chain hash table data in python

Tags: python, hashtable, chaining

I have a hash table in python and I have a lot of data and some are the same but I need to chain them.

I want to make a music database which if I search some numeric values called HZ i could find the name of the song.

So lets say I have a song Called Song 1 I measure it HZ values but their are countless 10 to be specific.

What I want to make is to have the ability to search any HZ value and have the same result.

```
Song 1
10 HZ 
20 HZ
30 HZ
40 HZ
50 HZ
60 HZ
70 HZ
80 HZ
90 HZ
100 HZ
```

So if I input any of these 10 values i would get the name Song 1 as results

Comment: Is 70 a 10 value? Do you want to get only Song 1 as the result or do you want Song 1 withing the results?

Comment: If your data is large you could also consider using a database. What do you mean by "their are countless 10 to be specific"?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a builtin dict. It's far more efficient then anything you could code yourself for most use cases.

It sounds like what you want is to simply store the song name as a value for each hertz value. If you have multiple songs that share a hertz, you could use a dict that stores sets (or just a defaultdict).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [`dict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) with [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list)s as values to store the data. Try something like:

```
music = {10: [<Song 1>, <Song 3>],
         20: [<Song 1>, <Song 2>]
        }
```

Now to see all songs that have 10HZ, just use:

```
music[10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter in your dictionary ("hash table") all HZ values as keys for the same `'Song 1'`.  It's highly probable that more than one song will have the same HZ value as other song.  In this case, you would like to keep the different songs associated to the same HZ in sets, so the values of your dictionary are sets of songs instead of individual ones.  The simplest way of achieving this is:

```
    from collections import defaultdict
    musicDirectory= defaultdict(set)

    musicDirectory[ 10].add( 'Song 1' )
    musicDirectory[ 40].add( 'Song 1' )
    musicDirectory[ 70].add( 'Song 1' )
    musicDirectory[100].add( 'Song 1' )
    musicDirectory[ 10].add( 'Song 2' )
    musicDirectory[ 70].add( 'Song 2' )
    musicDirectory[ 50].add( 'Song 2' )
    musicDirectory[ 10].add( 'Song 3' )
    musicDirectory[ 50].add( 'Song 3' )
    musicDirectory[ 70].add( 'Song 3' )

    print(40,"HZ=",musicDirectory[10])
    print(70,"HZ=",musicDirectory[10])
```

Should print:

```
    40 HZ= {'Song 1'}
    70 HZ= {'Song 2', 'Song 3', 'Song 1'}
```

Because there is only one song with HZ=40, but three of them with HZ=70.

Comment: there is a flaw in the code I noticed that if the number of data equals to the number of HZ are equal the results that come out are false but thank you it is exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: there is no prob it is perfect for what i am doing

Comment: @user2693902  I meant accept the answer so it doesn't remain open.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have 10 songs each with a frequencies but there are only 5 possible unique frequencies:

```
In [18]: import numpy as np

In [19]: from collections import defaultdict

In [20]: songs = [''.join(np.random.choice(list(letters), size=10).tolist()) for _ in range(10)]

In [21]: freqs = np.random.choice(range(10, 15), size=10).tolist()

In [22]: data = defaultdict(list)

In [23]: for freq, song in zip(freqs, songs):
   ....:     data[freq].append(song)
   ....:

In [24]: dict(data)
Out[24]:
{10: ['qlogxhxscp', 'eqxaeiyujp', 'wnhyprymyq', 'snsqquyvmv'],
 11: ['toibbjljxi', 'lqdxucnrpv', 'mrxxwmnxil'],
 13: ['lxcpzbswxx'],
 14: ['gmdbimcwon', 'zafhszrwss']}
```

Alternatively, use a `set` instead of a `list` if a song can have more than one frequency.